# Regex with a maximum value

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx:

```regex
(^\d{1,3}$)|(\d{1,3})\.?(\d{0,0}[0,5])
```

This accepts any `.5` increment of a number.

I want to add a range to this number of `13.5`. Ideally, `.5` should be valid to.

So, anything from `.5` to `13.5`, in `.5` increments.

Examples allowed:

```
.5
4
12.5
13.5
```

Not allowed:

```
.56
3.45
14
14.5
```

Comment: What behaviour about the current regex doesn't work, or do you want to change?

Comment: That it has no range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex has some big issues e.g. `[0,5]` doesn't mean either `0` or `5` but a `0`, `,` or `5`. Try the following regex instead:

```
^(?=.)(?:\d|1[0-3])?(?:\.5)?$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tTAwYB/1)

Based on your given allowed examples it matches `12` but doesn't match `12.0`. If you want to match `12.0` as well you have to replace `\.5` with `\.[05]`:

```
^(?=.)(?:\d|1[0-3])?(?:\.[05])?$
```

**Note**: postive lookahead `(?=.)` ensures that an empty match doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([0-9]|1[0-3])?(\.[05])?$
```

This works for your given examples